# Warning : No pom file was found, assuming default settings!

Tags: java, maven, maven-1

I installed Maven 1, following the doc here http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/start/install.html

Installation was successful, then I typed in "maven site" as shown in the doc here maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/start/quick-start.html

I get the error "Warning : No pom file was found, assuming default settings!"

From what I understand, maven 1 does not have pom file. Why is it prompting to me that the pom file was not found?

Thanks

Comment: Maven 1 doesn't have a POM file? How are you expected to define your project??

Comment: Didn't maven 1 use project.xml instead of pom.xml? God that was long ago ... :)

Comment: Yes, Maven 1 had a `project.xml` and `maven.xml`, `project.properties`, `build.properties` and this sends us back to 2003, dinosaur time!

Comment: yaa, it doesn't have pom file, thus I wonder why it prompts me for a pom file. I need to get it working on maven 1 before I can start migrating or customize the application.

Answer (score 6):

Since you're just starting out, may I suggest that you start over with the current, supported version of Maven.  [http://maven.apache.org](http://maven.apache.org/)/

Maven 1.x is obsoleted by Maven 2.2.x

Comment: Hi there,

Thanks for your reply. However, I need to customize an existing application done by another developer. To understand and debug the code, I need to be able to set it up on my local environment.

Comment: Understood; but I think the first step in taking control of this code should be to get it into a workable form. Upgrading to maven2 may take some work but it should prove a good investment of your time.

Answer (score 0):

> From what I understand, maven 1 does not have pom file. Why is it prompting to me that the pom file was not found?

Maven 1.x had a Project Object Model (POM) too, it was just not called `pom.xml` but `project.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running the command from the correct directory.

If the directory you are running from doesn't contain the project files, it could give you this error. At least, that was my issue :)